# Tar files from two different directories

Tags: cmd, tar

So I was wondewring how I should write my command, so I tar files from two directories. Normally I've just done it using one, but now I need to use two directories. I should about writing it like this, but that doesn't work.

```sh
tar --directory=
build/Files/TestReports/iPer
build/Files/TestReports/Netx 
-cjvf %TEMP_UUID%.tar.bz2
```

Or should I select the `TestReports` folder instead, and somehow tell it to only look at `iPer`  and `Netx`

```sh
tar --directory=
build/Files/TestReports/* iPer Netx
-cjvf %TEMP_UUID%.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I've used https://linuxhint.com/linux-tar-command/ for commands

Comment: What does `-a` do?

Comment: But why should i use -a then? I need both files (from different locations) to be in the same `.bz2`

Comment: @KJ Can't I just write `tar --directory=
build/Files/TestReports/iPer  --directory=
build/Files/TestReports/Netx
-cjvf %TEMP_UUID%.tar.bz2`

Comment: Okay, thanks I will keep a note on that then, but else the suggested command I wrote in the other comment should work? Or should there be a `/*` in the end of the path to tell it to fetch all in the folder?